# c# WCF REST DATETIME displayed as /Date(1462399200000+0200)

Tags: c#

I have a .mdf database which looks like this:
Table kosarica:

[datum_zakljucenega_nakupa] DATETIME NULL, 
and other values which are not important right now.

In my model I have a :

```
[DataMember]
public DateTime datum_zakljucenega_nakupa{get;set;}
```

This is in my Service1.SVC

```
 public List<Kosarica> Kosarica()
        {
            using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                myConn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Kosarica;", myConn);
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<Kosarica> kosarice = new List<Kosarica>();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Kosarica k = new Kosarica();
                    k.Id = (int)rdr["Id"];



                   k.datum_zakljucenega_nakupa = (DateTime)rdr["datum_zakljucenega_nakupa"];



                    kosarice.Add(k);
                }
                myConn.Close();
                return kosarice;

            }

        }
```

There are other values in here which are not important right now. When I run Postman all other values display correctly except for the datetime which shows:
/Date(1462399200000+0200)

I have tried parsing it with various ways, but it didn't work. The "datetime" which postman returns is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the DateTime as a formatted string, you need to edit your model:

Example:

```
k.datum_zakljucenega_nakupa = ((DateTime)rdr["datum_zakljucenega_nakupa"]).toString("dd-MM-YYYY");
```

Comment: thanks it worked, will mark for answer but I have to wait 4 minutes now